# Unable to access a particular id from kivy file to my python ERROR "AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'"

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

The main code <main.py>

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior

class Background(Widget):
    cloud_texture = ObjectProperty(None)
    tree1_texture = ObjectProperty(None)
    tree2_texture = ObjectProperty(None)
    grass_texture = ObjectProperty(None)
    bush_texture = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cloud_texture = Image(source="cloud.png").texture
        self.cloud_texture.wrap = 'repeat'
        self.cloud_texture.uvsize = (Window.width/ self.cloud_texture.width, -1)

        self.tree1_texture = Image(source="tree_1.png").texture
        self.tree1_texture.wrap = 'repeat'
        self.tree1_texture.uvsize = (Window.width/ self.tree1_texture.width, -1)

        self.tree2_texture = Image(source="tree_2.png").texture
        self.tree2_texture.wrap = 'repeat'
        self.tree2_texture.uvsize = (Window.width/ self.tree2_texture.width, -1)

        self.grass_texture = Image(source="grass.png").texture
        self.grass_texture.wrap = 'repeat'
        self.grass_texture.uvsize = (Window.width/ self.grass_texture.width, -1)

        self.bush_texture = Image(source="bush.png").texture
        self.bush_texture.wrap = 'repeat'
        self.bush_texture.uvsize = (Window.width/ self.bush_texture.width, -1)

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.cloud_texture.uvsize = (self.width / self.cloud_texture.width, -1)
        self.tree1_texture.uvsize = (self.width / self.tree1_texture.width, -1)
        self.tree2_texture.uvsize = (self.width / self.tree2_texture.width, -1)
        self.grass_texture.uvsize = (self.width / self.grass_texture.width, -1)
        self.bush_texture.uvsize = (self.width / self.grass_texture.width, -1)

    def scroll_textures(self, time_passed):
        self.cloud_texture.uvpos = ((self.cloud_texture.uvpos[0] + time_passed/8.0)% Window.width , self.cloud_texture.uvpos[1])
        self.tree1_texture.uvpos = ((self.tree1_texture.uvpos[0] + time_passed/2.0)% Window.width , self.tree1_texture.uvpos[1])
        self.tree2_texture.uvpos = ((self.tree2_texture.uvpos[0] + time_passed/2.0)% Window.width , self.tree2_texture.uvpos[1])
        self.grass_texture.uvpos = ((self.grass_texture.uvpos[0] + time_passed/8.0)% Window.width , self.grass_texture.uvpos[1])
        self.bush_texture.uvpos = ((self.bush_texture.uvpos[0] + time_passed/8.0)% Window.width , self.bush_texture.uvpos[1])

        texture = self.property('cloud_texture')
        texture.dispatch(self)

        texture = self.property('tree1_texture')
        texture.dispatch(self)

        texture = self.property('tree2_texture')
        texture.dispatch(self)

        texture = self.property('grass_texture')
        texture.dispatch(self)

        texture = self.property('bush_texture')
        texture.dispatch(self)

        print("scroll")

    pass

    def on_stop(self):
        pass

class StartWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(StartWindow,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    pass

class GameWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GameWindow,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    pass

class OptionsWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(OptionsWindow,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return super().__getattr__(attr)

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.root.ids.background.scroll_textures,1/60.)
        pass


MainApp().run()
```

The line "Clock.schedule_interval(g.ids.background.scroll_textures,1/60.)" is not working. I am not understanding the fundamental way to call the id from the kv file.

main.kv file

```
 WindowManager:
    StartWindow:
    GameWindow:
    OptionsWindow:

<StartWindow>:
    name: "start"
    id: startwindow
    FloatLayout:
        cols:4
        Image:
            source: 'Flying_whale.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0,"y":0.50}
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            color: 0,0,0,1
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 17**3.3
            text: "Start!"
            id: set_event
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
                root.on_start()
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.15,"y":0.25}
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            color: 0,0,0,1
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 17**3.5
            text: "Options"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                app.root.current = "options"
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.15,"y":0.10}
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            color: 0,0,0,1
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 17**3.5
            text: "Exit"
<GameWindow>
    name:"game"
    id: gamewindow
    FloatLayout:
        Background:
            id: background
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    source: "sky.png"
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.width, 150
                    pos: self.pos[0],self.pos[1] + self.height - 138
                    texture: self.cloud_texture
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.width, 160
                    pos: self.pos[0],self.pos[1]
                    texture: self.grass_texture
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.width, 100
                    pos: self.pos[0]-10,self.pos[1] + 145
                    texture: self.tree1_texture
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.width, 100
                    pos: self.pos[0]+30,self.pos[1] + 160
                    texture: self.tree2_texture
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.width, 20
                    pos: self.pos[0],self.pos[1] + 155
                    texture: self.bush_texture
            Label:
                id: score
                size_hint_y : None
                height : 96
                text: "0"
                font_size: 40

            Button:
                pos_hint:{"x":0,"y":0.25}
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                color: 0,0,0,1
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 17**3.3
                text: "Back"
                id: set_event
                on_release:
<OptionsWindow>:
    name: "options"
    FloatLayout:
        cols:4
        Image:
            source: 'Flying_whale.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.15,"y":0.20}
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            color: 0,0,0,1
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 17**3.5
            text: "Back"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                app.root.current = "start"
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.15,"y":0.35}
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            color: 1,1,1,1
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 17**3.5
            text: "Mode : Night / Day"
```

The error is given by:

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

I know it is a simple understanding problem but I am not able to work around it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `id: background` is defined in the `GameWindow` rule in the `kv`. According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#ids):

> When the kv file is processed, weakrefs to all the widgets tagged with
> ids are added to the root widget’s ids dictionary.

While the term `root widget` is over used and has different meanings depending on context, here it means the `rule` that contains the `id`. So the `background` `id` will only appear in the `ids` of the `GamWindow` widget.

Knowing that, your questionable line of code can be replaced with:

```
Clock.schedule_interval(self.root.get_screen('game').ids.background.scroll_textures,1/60.)
```

The above code uses `get_screen()` to access the `GameWindow`.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue after a while. Thank you for your feedback. I am able to understand the problem further.